# Can any one please tell me the open button functionality code (Which can be open our directory of a PC) of a Dialog box in mfc

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I have a dialog box and it consists a OPEN Button, when i click the Button it will re direct to the Windows explorer where can i choose any file in my directory

Comment: Hard to understand your question. Are you looking for the CFileDialog class?

Comment: I have a one Dialog box and inside the Dialog i have one Button like..Open. So when i click the open Button it will redirect to File Explorer. I would like to that code!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bare minimum is:

```
CFileDialog dlg(TRUE);
if (IDOK == dlg.DoModal())
{
   CString strFileName = dlg.GetPathName();
   // do stuff with file name
}
```

I'd suggest you read/search more for what you can do with CFileDialog. You can pass filters, you can set flags to allow more than one file to be selected. But above is probably the bare minimum to open/select a file.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can I give the any path inside the GetPathName()??

Comment: I don't understand the question. There are no arguments to GetPathName()

Comment: @ari: You can set the `lpstrInitialDir` of the [CFileDialog::m_ofn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class#m_ofn) member prior to displaying the dialog to have it navigate to that directory. This appears to be unsupported when using the Vista (or later) style MFC dialog, although I haven't tested.

Comment: Hi Joseph, Can you please let me know how to pass the class name and reference inside the CList Class in mfc. Exmaple, CList<class name, reference> cl; can you please suggest me some code about the exmaple.

Comment: Say, for a list of strings: CList<CString> listOfStrings; listOfStrings.AddTail(_T("abcdef"));  For most classes you only need the first template argument--in this case the CString.